# structures and pointers

Tags: c++

I'm not sure what I'm doing...

Let say I have a structure

```
struct Inner{
    exampleType a;
    int b;
}

struct Outer{
    int current;
    int total;
    Inner records[MAXNUMBER];
}

struct Outer2{
    Outer outer;
}
```

And I have the following functions:

```
void try3( Outer2& outer, type var, type2 var2 ){
}

void try2( Outer2* outer ){
    try3(*outer, var, var2);
}
```

Inside main:

```
int myMain( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    Outer2 outer2;
    try2 (&outer2);
}
```

Here's the question. Can I increment the value of current by sticking the following line in try3:

```
++outer.outer.current;
```

Comment: well, first of all I don't see any symbol named outer2 inside the body of the function try3()...

Comment: There is no `outer2` in try3. You also have never initialized any of the integers anywhere. Try doing what you're trying to do, then see what happens.

Comment: i just made a correction to my post.

Comment: @Brian Won't it be zero-initialized since they're PODs?

Comment: @Brian Assuming exampleType is a POD.

Comment: @user470379: Only at global (or namespace) scope, I believe.

Comment: Certainly not. Try it ;)

Comment: @Brian I prefer not to rely on quick trials and firsthand experience to see if something is potentially undefined, but doing some more research, it appears I was mistaken. I updated my answer below to show that.

Comment: @Brian Actually, I'm starting to go back the other way now: according to the standard, "(12.6.1) When no initializer is specified for an object of (possibly cv-qualified) class type (or array thereof), or the initializer has the form (), the object is initialized as specified in 8.5. The object is default-initialized if there is no initializer, or value-initialized if the initializer is ()." Then "(8.5.5) To default-initialize an object of type T means: if T is a non-POD class type... if T is an array type... otherwise, the object is zero-initialized."

Comment: @Brian Finally "(8.5.4) To zero-initialize an object of type T means: if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T; if T is a non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized."

Comment: Of course, then again "(8.5.9) If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof)...; if the object is of const-qualified type... . Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a non-static object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value." I'm officially confused now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `try3`, you would need to use `++outer.outer.current` since `outer` is the name of the variable at the point. To answer the actual question though,  look at the two functions. `try2` takes a pointer to an `Outer2`, so no copy is made. `try2` passes this to `try3` which take a reference to an `Outer2`, so again no copy is made. This means that yes, `++outer.outer.current` will in fact affect the original `outer2` declared in `myMain`.

**Edit** (per Brian's comment)

However, `outer.outer.current` is never initialized, unless that's not your true `myMain`, so the final value of `current` is undefined since the value was never defined before the increment.

Comment: Except none of the variables have been initialized, so the behavior will still be undefined.

Comment: I believe you would need to use `outer.outer.current` because the `outer` in `try3` takes an `Outer2` object called `outer` which also has a member variable called `outer`.

Answer (score 2):

errr, no,  try3 has no knowledge of a thing caller outer2.

you can go outer.outer.current++;   in try3

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, why not? Here is a working example for you:

```
typedef short exampleType;

struct Inner
{
    exampleType a;
    int b;
};

struct Outer
{
    enum { MAXNUMBER = 2 };

    int current;
    int total;
    Inner records[MAXNUMBER];
};

struct Outer2
{
    Outer outer;
};

typedef int type;
typedef int type2;

void try3 (Outer2& outer, type var, type2 var2)
{
    ++outer.outer.current;
}

void try2 (Outer2* outer)
{
    int var = 1, var2 = 2;
    ++outer->outer.current;
    try3(*outer, var, var2);
}

int main ()
{
    Outer2 outer2;
    outer2.outer.current = 1986;
    try2 (&outer2);
}
```